# Why is $-fg^2$ analytic only if whenever $g$ has a pole of order $m$, $f$ has a zero of order at least $2m$?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm reading a proof of a lemma, and in one step the author uses the following:

> Let $D$ be a domain in the complex plane, $g$ an arbitrary meromorphic function in $D$ and $f$ be an analytic function. Then $-fg^2$ is analytic only if $f$ has the property that whenever $g$ has a pole of order $m$, $f$ has a zero of order at least $2m$.

and although it's probably obvious, I haven't been able to see it. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively, if $g$ has a pole of order $m$ at $z_0$ it is like $\frac a{(z-z_0)^m}$ plus smaller corrections with $a$ some constant.  To make $g^2$ analytic you need to multiply it by something like $b(z-z_0)^{2m}$.  Terms with higher powers of $z-z_0$ are fine, but if you have one with a lower power it won't cancel all the $z-z_0$s in the denominator.

Comment: Sure. But how do the zeros of $f$ relate to this?

Comment: If $f$ is $b(z-z_0)^{2m}$ it has a zero of order $2m$ at $z_0$.  We can add in more terms as long as they have even more factors of $z-z_0$

Comment: Thanks! But why couldn't $f$ be, say, $b(z-z_0)^{m+1}$?

Comment: Because $g$ is squared you would get $(z-z_0)^{1-m}$ with that.  For $m \gt 1$ that is still a pole

Comment: Oh that's right... my fault. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The "only if" language is not the best. It means

> If $fg^2$ is analytic, then $f$ has a zero of order at least $2m$ at any point where $g$ has a pole of order $m$.

Is it obvious now?

Comment: Not really. Why does it hold?